# How in Django, make form.field availiable to modify after push the button

Tags: django, button, request

for example I have form.email
And I want to modify this field after push button "Change email".
Code looks like below.
Template:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if mod_availiable == True %}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"</span>
  {% else %}
    {{ email }} 
  {% endif %}

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="profile_update"/>

</form>


<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Change Email" name="change_email"/>
</form>
```

View:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
  context = super(UserUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  context['mod_availiable'] = False
  return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    if "change_email" in request.POST:
      context = get_context()
      context['mod_availiable'] = True
    return super(ProfileChange, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

After hitting `Change email` button, `mod_availiable` won't be `True` according my `post()` code.

Comment: Sorry, a bit unclear to me: do you want the form to become available after hitting the button, or the form to be submitted?

Comment: field of form to be availiable to modify, after push "change" button, then post this value hitting "Update" button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "change_email" in request.POST:
        form = self.get_form()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form,'mod_availiable': True})
```

template.html:

```
                            <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

                                {% for f in form %}
                                    {% if f.name == 'email'%}

                                        {% if mod_availiable == True %}
                                            {{ f }}
                                        {% else %}
                                            {{ f.value }} 
                                            <input type="submit" value="Check" name="email_verify"/>
                                            <form action="" method="post">
                                                <input type="submit" value="Change Email" name="change_email"/>
                                            </form>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% else %}
                                        {{ f }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <br>
                                {% endfor %}


                                <input type="submit" value="Update" name="profile_update"/>

                            </form>
```

That was the main problem.
But still looks ugly, in case this is UpdateView -> context Won't update after button pushes.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if I understand your "question". But is this what you want to do?

```
{% if mod_availiable %}
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </form>
{% else %}
    {{ email }} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Quite yes, but How to handle mod_availiable == True in this scenario ?

Comment: I mean, how to reach {% else %} branch after press the button?

Comment: You can put wathever you want in there. The {% else %} block is reached when the user did NOT press the button. You could show them their current email for example

Comment: Nope, I can't get email, after hitting button

Comment: You'll have to put the email in the context-object obviously. Otherwise post your whole view so we can help you better